# DOCKER-ISOLATION iptables rule is blocking network bridge to forward traffic

Tags: iptables, virtualization, linux-networking, docker, bridge

I have a server that runs KVM and Docker. The physical machine has the IP `192.168.1.13`, and the machine inside KVM has `192.168.1.40`, with its port bridged to the physical network interface on the physical machine. The problem is that the outside world cannot access the VM, and vice versa. But the host machine is able to access both outside world and the VM.

This is the `ifconfig` result on the host machine:

```
... (lo interface ignored)

br-5c76c0836bc3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f8:92:8d:06  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:f8ff:fe92:8d06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:496 (496.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:41:9e:bc:0f  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:41ff:fe9e:bc0f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72555 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:8895509 (8.8 MB)

veth312b28e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:2c:1c:a1:93:d6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::542c:1cff:fea1:93d6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:142 (142.0 B)  TX bytes:13511363 (13.5 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:**:**:**:**:d5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::96de:80ff:fed9:e8d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8668453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7807533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18268047855 (18.2 GB)  TX bytes:8304004607 (8.3 GB)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:**:**:**:**:d5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::96de:80ff:fed9:e8d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16943241 errors:0 dropped:289 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10558830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19001088198 (19.0 GB)  TX bytes:8478281605 (8.4 GB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:**:**:0c  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70397 (70.3 KB)  TX bytes:11914 (11.9 KB)
```

And this is the `brctl show` result:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-5c76c0836bc3         8000.0242f8928d06       no
br0             8000.94de80d9e8d5       yes             enp2s0
                                                        vnet0
docker0         8000.0242419ebc0f       no              veth312b28e
virbr0          8000.000000000000       yes
```

I investigated the problem, and found that iptables is dropping my packet.

```
# iptables -x -v --line-numbers -L FORWARD                                                                               1 ↵
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 7422 packets, 740173 bytes)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
3           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            
4           0        0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5           0        0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6       31719  2588550 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
7           1       40 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8           1       44 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
9           1       44 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
10          0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
11          0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-5c76c0836bc3  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
12          0        0 DOCKER     all  --  any    br-5c76c0836bc3  anywhere             anywhere            
13          0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-5c76c0836bc3 !br-5c76c0836bc3  anywhere             anywhere            
14          0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-5c76c0836bc3 br-5c76c0836bc3  anywhere             anywhere
```

When pinging from the VM to the outside world, the `policy DROP` counter, along with the `pkts` counter of line 6, will increase 1 with every ICMP echo packet. How can this happen? How to fix it?

Comment: It looks like `iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT` temporarily solves the problem. But what's the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this is not the fault of `DOCKER-ISOLATION`, but due to the option `bridge-nf-call-iptables` turned on. Turning that on will lead iptables to process the traffic, and thus dropping the packet.